# sed regex with variables to replace numbers in a file

Tags: linux, perl, sed

Im trying to replace numbers in my textfile by adding one to them. i.e.

```
sed 's/3/4/g' path.txt
sed 's/2/3/g' path.txt
sed 's/1/2/g' path.txt
```

Instead of this, Can i automate it, i.e. find a /d and add one to it in the replace.

Something like

```
sed 's/\([0-8]\)/\1+1/g' path.txt
```

Also wanted to capture more than one digit i.e. `([0-9])\t([0-9])` and change each one keeping the tab inbetween

Thanks

edited #2
Using the perl example,
I also would like it to work with more digits  i.e.

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/ ($1+1)\.($2+1)\.($3+1)\.($4+1) /ge' output.txt
```

Any tips on making the above work?

Comment: And when you hit 9? What about double-digit numbers?

Comment: Your right! it should be [0-8] so it doesn't hit double digits.

Answer (score 6):

There is no support for arithmetic in `sed`, but you can easily do this in Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/ $1+1 /ge'
```

With the `/e` option, the replacement expression needs to be valid Perl code.  So to handle your final updated example, you need

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/ $1+1 . "." $2+1 . "." . $3+1 . "." . $4+1 /ge'
```

where strings are properly quoted and adjacent strings are concatenated together with the `.` Perl string concatenation operator. (The arithmetic numbers are coerced into strings as well when they are concatenated with a string.)

... Though of course, the first script already does that more elegantly, since with the `/g` flag it already increments every sequence of digits with one, anywhere in the string.

Comment: Actually Perl can do in-place editing, so `perl -pi~ -e 's/(\d+)/ 1+$1 /ge' *.txt`

Comment: @goldilocks: Actually your loop code is wrong in multiple places; but as per my last comment, not much point in fixing it.

Comment: "Wrong" in the sense that it loops thru all .txt files and performs the substitution correctly? ;|

Comment: No, incorrectly, both in the Perl code and the surrounding shell code.

Comment: @goldilocks at first look you set `$b` to the output of a perl script and not to a filename. You're `echo`ing the filename as input to perl instead of its contents... And so on.

Comment: Thanks, Using the perl, How do i use two variables i.e. perl -pe 's/(\d+)\t(\d+)/ $1+1 $2+1 /ge' ?

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: Ah, I read the OP wrongly (to rename files, not edit contents).  Sorry.

Comment: The `/g` option already causes it to loop over each match on each line.

Comment: To belatedly clarify, the script above handles every instance of a sequence digits anywhere on a line already.  But if you do want to match specifically on the first instance of two numbers with a tab between them, `s/(\d+)\t(\d+)/$1+1 . "\t" . $2+1 /e` where literal strings need to be concatenated with `.` and quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Triplee's perl solution is the more generic answer, but Michal's sed solution works well for this particular case.  However, Michal's sed solution is more easily written:

```
sed y/12345678/23456789/ path.txt
```

and is better implemented as

```
tr 12345678 23456789 < path.txt
```

This utterly fails to handle 2 digit numbers (as in the edited question).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` but it's not easy, see [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed).

And it's hard with awk too, [see this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/how-to-use-regrex-with-awk-for-string-replacement-in-this-example).

I'd rather use `perl` for this ([something like this can be seen in action @ ideone](http://ideone.com/UWdEl)):

```
perl -pe 's/([0-8])/$1+1/e'
```

(The ideone.com example must have some looping as ideone does not sets `-pe` by default.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do addition directly in `sed` - you could do it in `awk` by matching numbers using a regex in each line and increasing the value, but it's quite complicated. If do not need to handle arbitrary numbers but a limited set, like only single-digit numbers from 0 to 8, you can just put several replacement commands on a single `sed` command line by separating them with semicolons:

```
sed 's/8/9/g ; s/7/8/g; s/6/7/g; s/5/6/g; s/4/5/g; s/3/4/g; s/2/3/g; s/1/2/g; s/0/1/g' path.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed 's/[0-9]/$((&+1))/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

This will add one to every individual digit, to increment numbers:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/$((&+1))/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

N.B. This method is fraught with problems and may cause unexpected results.